# How to conditionally format if not on list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2003

Every tip online about conditional formatting and a list is about highlighting cells that match on the list. How can I highlight cells that don't match (ignoring blank cells).

For example, a list of times at 15 minute intervals, hh:mm AM/PM format:

5:00 AM
5:15 AM
5:30 AM
5:45 AM
6:00 AM And so on...

And a column of entries, conditionally formatted:

5:30 AM
6:15 AM
7AM
830 AM

The first two entries are fine. How to conditionally format to highlight the last two entries (to warn the user to retype) as not being on the list? (For example, check for absence of colon (":")?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its only about validating for the correct time format, you can also use Data > Data Tools > Data Validation. Set to allow "Time" only. You may then also set an input and error message to help guide the user (other tabs in the the Data validation dialogue box).

Failing that, and to answer your original question. Simply define your custom new rule using a formula (assuming you are entering the data in A1) and the approved list is named *list*:

```
=ISNA(MATCH(A1,list,0))
```

Match will return #N/A when it is unable to find the item in the list. ISNA() turns this into TRUE, causing the highlight to occur.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I didn't want to use DV because I just wanted to fill the cell with color, not reject the entry or create a pop-up message. What you provided works great, but would there be a way to ignore blank cells? I even included a blank cell in my list, but conditional formatting isn't recognizing it, so all blank cells become filled.

Comment: Ah yes you can combine it with an AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),ISNA(MATCH(A1,list,0))) works perfectly!

Comment: Ughhh spoke too soon: the formula seemed to work when applied to a pre-existing list of times. But then I started testing by manually entering some times, and random times are not being found in the list. Evaluating suggests that it's trying to match decimal to time. But some times are still being found, so now I'm really confused.

Comment: Do you only want valid time in 15 min intervals in am/pm format with ":"? So it should reject 6h30 and 6:31? Even 6:15 because it doesnt have 6:15 AM?

Comment: How about this, you leave Excel to automatically determine if the entered value is a valid time according to the computers regional settings. If you use `MINUTE` it will return an error if it isn't properly formatted. Now to CF filter for 15min intervals: `=IFERROR(MOD(MINUTE(A1),15)=0, FALSE)`

Comment: You can even apply two CF rules, say colour the cell red if its not a valid time and orange if its not at a 15min interval.

Comment: Also, check here https://excel.tips.net/T003292_Checking_for_Time_Input.html

Comment: Thank you so much! `MINUTE` was the gamechanger! I'm basically ok with any time at this point, just care more about the format. `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),NOT(IFERROR(MINUTE(A1)>=0, FALSE)))` is the final answer!

Comment: One caveat. Excel basically stores time and date as a time serial number or number of days since 1/1/1900 incl fractions for hours minutes etc. So MINUTE will not throw an error when called on a number.  To be doubly sure also `FIND(":",A1&"")`